# Multiple Parameter Servers for cifar10_estimator on TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-estimator

I'm recently working on distributed TensorFlow training, and I'm running cifar10_estimator from [tutorial folder in TensorFlow's model repository.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10_estimator)

It's totally fine when I running the code with 1 PS(parameter server), 1 Master, and multiple workers. But when it comes to multiple PS, the master crashed while raising the error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: /job:ps/replica:0/task:1/device:CPU:0 unknown device.
```

I'm using TF_CONFIG as follow(2 PS, 1 master, 3 workers):

```
export TF_CONFIG='{"task": {"task": 0, "type": "ps"}, "environment": "cloud", 
 "cluster": {"worker": ["10.140.0.3:8000", "10.140.0.5:8000", "10.140.0.6:8000"], 
 "master": ["10.140.0.2:8000"], "ps": ["10.140.0.4:8000", "10.140.0.19:8000"]}, 
 "model_dir": "gs://[bucket]/cifar10_model/"}'
```

and run the code as follow.

```
Master and Worker:
    python cifar10_main.py --data-dir=gs://[bucket]/cifar-10-data --job-dir=gs://[bucket]/cifar10_model/ --num-gpus=1 --train-steps=1000 --sync

PS:
    python cifar10_main.py --data-dir=gs://[bucket]/cifar-10-data --job-dir=gs://[bucket]/cifar10_model/ --num-gpus=0
```

All of the instances are on Google Cloud Platform.

Is there some faults in my TF_CONFIG or what, or I simply cannot run multiple PS using the cifar10_estimator code provided?

Comment: Why do you have "task" again inside "task"? My understanding is that the values should be index and type inside task.

Comment: I use "task": {"index": 0, "type": "ps"} before, but this raised some error prevent me from setting the workers. Then I found a workaround to change the "index" to "task", which solved my problem.
I can't find the reference webpage now since I worked on this work a couple months ago...

Comment: That's interesting. I was looking for this and couldn't find clarifications either. I wonder why this would work. Did you manage to solve this issue using two parameter servers?

Comment: Nah. I leave it to 1PS v.s 16 workers
Therefore the network is definitely a bottleneck.